# Android: A class that exist and Logcat log that it could not be found

Tags: android, classnotfound

I tried to import a project developed on my laptop to another PC.

I am sure that project work very well on my laptop, but on the new pc, the application crashes telling me that it could not find a class:

```
04-05 10:32:26.802: D/dalvikvm(568): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1062 objects / 72728 bytes in 48ms
04-05 10:32:28.492: D/dalvikvm(568): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 270 objects / 14312 bytes in 39ms
04-05 10:32:28.653: D/dalvikvm(568): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 77 objects / 3184 bytes in 37ms
04-05 10:32:29.242: E/dalvikvm(568): Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper', referenced from method com.test.two.MockRecipesControllerString.<init>
04-05 10:32:29.653: W/dalvikvm(568): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 710 (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper;) in Lcom/test/two/MockRecipesControllerString;
04-05 10:32:29.653: D/dalvikvm(568): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000e
04-05 10:32:29.693: D/dalvikvm(568): VFY: dead code 0x0010-001e in Lcom/test/two/MockRecipesControllerString;.<init> (Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
04-05 10:32:29.733: I/dalvikvm(568): Could not find method org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.createJsonParser, referenced from method com.test.two.MockRecipesControllerString.init
```

The library and the class exist.

What can I do to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming class ObjectMapper(org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper) is in a Jar file as a Lib, Add the Lib Again..Clean Build the Project..It will Work..

Answer (score 0):

select your project right click ->properties -> check you build path add libraries in java this might help..